# Heating element for fabrics

Tags: heater

I'm trying to make some heated gloves and socks that would work with standard Li-Ion batteries. There are some ready-made solutions out there but they are either very expensive or have small heated areas.

The only options I found so far are some specialty carbon textiles that also seem to be very expensive, or cannibalizing some USB heating pads, which don't seem to work very well according to the reviews...

Assuming that the circuit will work at 3.7V and 0.5-2A (putting out between 2-8W), what would be my options when it comes to choosing a heating element for this purpose?

Comment: one of the options to consider is the location of the heating element in the glove

Comment: You probably have very few options. Getting even current density will be a major challenge as anything like a point connection will result in hot spots. See https://freefem.org/.

Comment: Maybe you could experiment with the wires from a low-voltage electric blanket. How's you knitting?

Comment: Consider a length of resistive wire, such as nichrome, to spread the heat over a larger area.  How you insulate that from itself (electrically), while making a soft, flexible, and long-lasting glove, sounds like the stuff nightmares are made of. :)